# Collapsible Toolbar - Make Fragment Footer Always Visible in Android

Tags: android, xml, android-fragments, android-coordinatorlayout, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

I am making an app that has a ProfilePage with three fragments - About | Posts | Gallery, and I am using a collapsible toolbar with user's image. My second and third fragment will have a footer that should always be visible, but this is what I get:

[image]
[image]

When my image is expanded the footer disappears. What I want is for my two fragments to have these footers always visible and not depending on toolbar being collapsed or not. My gallery footer should be similar to post footer.

**profile_layout.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout    
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
   android:id="@+id/main_content"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="256dp"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/profile_image"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:contentDescription="@string/profile_photo"
            app:layout_collapseMode="none"/>

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/toolbarEdit"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="end"
                android:contentDescription="@string/block"
                android:paddingEnd="20dp"
                android:paddingStart="5dp"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_icon_edit" />
        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/myProfileTabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        app:tabContentStart="72dp"
        app:tabGravity="fill"
        app:tabMode="scrollable" />

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/myProfileViewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />
</LinearLayout>
```

**posts_fragment.xml:**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/tile_bg"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/list_view_messages"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="@null"
    android:divider="@null"
    android:transcriptMode="alwaysScroll"
    android:stackFromBottom="true">
</ListView>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/llMsgCompose"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="4" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/inputMsg"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:background="@color/bg_msg_input"
        android:textColor="@color/text_msg_input"
        android:paddingLeft="6dp"
        android:paddingRight="6dp"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnSend"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@color/ppdColorOrange"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:text="@string/send" />
</LinearLayout>
```

**My PostsFragment** (not yet implemented):

```java
public class MyProfilePostsFragment extends Fragment {     
    @Override     
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {          
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.navdrawer_my_profile_fragment_posts, container, false);         
        return view;
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same requirement for my one of apps. I just did workaround.
Add your required layout in tab layout:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout    
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
   android:id="@+id/main_content"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="256dp"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/profile_image"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:contentDescription="@string/profile_photo"
                app:layout_collapseMode="none"/>

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/toolbarEdit"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="end"
                    android:contentDescription="@string/block"
                    android:paddingEnd="20dp"
                    android:paddingStart="5dp"
                    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_icon_edit" />
            </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/myProfileTabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            app:tabContentStart="72dp"
            app:tabGravity="fill"
            app:tabMode="scrollable" />

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/myProfileViewpager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <-- Your required layout -->
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/tab123"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:gravity="bottom"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:weightSum="4">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/inputMsg"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="3"
            android:paddingLeft="6dp"
            android:paddingRight="6dp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnSend"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="send" />
    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Add following code in your Tab activity:

```java
TabLayout tabLayout;    
tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);//add your viewpager to TabLayout 

tabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {

    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
        viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
        LinearLayout l=(LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.tab123);
        final EditText text=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputMsg);
        Button send=(Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSend);

        if (tab.getPosition() == 0) {
            l.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            System.out.println("About tab");
        } else if (tab.getPosition() == 1) {
            l.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            System.out.println("Posts tab");

            send.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    String msg = null;
                    msg = text.getText().toString(); //get input
                    // Perform your desired task.
                }
            });
        } else if (tab.getPosition() == 2) {
            l.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            System.out.println("Gallery tab");

            send.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    String msg = null;
                    msg = text.getText().toString(); //get input
                    //Perform your desired task.
                }
            });
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer Shashidhar. Would I have to add my gallery_fragment.xml to tab layout as well? Also does this mean I would have to change my Fragments and add this layout to all of them them? Is there a cleaner solution for this?

Comment: @Kemo, Just remove linear layout from all fragment as we have added to tab xml file.

Comment: Tried it and it works beautifully. One question - what should I do with my fragment - how should I implement it, because I would have to edit that as well. When I enter the message and click enter, how would I display it, in my fragment or activity? Do I need to combine it with MainActivity that has these fragments. I am using this [tutoiral](http://www.androidhive.info/2016/02/android-push-notifications-using-gcm-php-mysql-realtime-chat-app-part-1/).

Comment: Also, how would I display listview from posts_fragment.xml above the footer?

Comment: This is a very elegant solution, I have already used it on another part of my app to display different FABs for different fragments. Thanks again Shashidhar :)

Comment: @Kemo, Happy coding!