# FloatingActionButton inside ViewPager + CollapsingToolbarLayout

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, material-design

I'm having some issues setting an FloatingActionButton in a layout with a CollapsingToolbarLayout.

**Sources:**

I'm using this project as base: [Android-Material-Design-for-pre-Lollipop](https://github.com/Suleiman19/Android-Material-Design-for-pre-Lollipop)

Blog post: [Create a Parallax Scrolling Header with Tabs in Android](https://android.jlelse.eu/parallax-scrolling-header-tabs-android-tutorial-2cc6e40aa257)

[image]

**Layout:**
Basically you have the following structure in the main layout:

```
-CoordinatorLayout
  -AppBar
    -CollapsingToolbar
       -Image (Parallax)
       -Toolbar
       -TabLayout
  -ViewPager
```

Then the adapter of the ViewPager provides the content of every tab.

**The problem:**
I want some tabs to have their own floating action button. Since not all tabs are going to have it I'd like to add it inside the ViewPager's adapter.

But when adding the button to the page layout make it to appear at the end of the scroll of the scrollable content, that is, you need to scroll down collapsing the bar to see the floating button.

In contrast if you add the FloatingActionButton to the main layout (at the same level than the ViewPager) you are using a single "shared" button for all tabs so you need to create a communication between the PagerAdapter content (in my case fragments) and the main layout in order to:

- Hide and show the button according to the curren page
- Update the icon + accessibility label
- Propagate click event to the ViewPager's fragment

This second option sounds not very clean.

Update:
I noticed that some of my tabs also have list with footer which needs to be clipped to the bottom and after implementing the `appbar_scrolling_view_behavior` are broken too =(

**Similar Questions:**

[Collapsible Toolbar - Make Fragment Footer Always Visible in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43140250/collapsible-toolbar-make-fragment-footer-always-visible-in-android): Started a bounty for a more clean solution

How can I solve this problem?

MainLayout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/htab_maincontent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/htab_appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/htab_collapse_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="256dp"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed|snap"
            app:titleEnabled="false">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/htab_header"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@drawable/header"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"/>

            <View
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:alpha="0.3"
                android:background="@android:color/black"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"/>

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/htab_toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:layout_gravity="top"
                android:layout_marginBottom="48dp"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"/>

            <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                android:id="@+id/htab_tabs"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                app:tabIndicatorColor="@android:color/white"
                app:tabSelectedTextColor="@android:color/white"
                app:tabTextColor="@color/white_70"/>

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/htab_viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: show your layout design code.

Comment: prefer the answer and let me know the scenario.